# What's the best way to initialise a logger in a class?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

I've got two options to initialise a `Logger` within a class.

The first way is providing an instance of the `Class<?>`:

```
logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SignUpController.class);
```

and the second one is passing a `String` identifier (the package and the class name):

```
logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("controller.SignUpController");
```

The questions are:

What's the best way to initialise a logger for a class?
What modifiers should be used with? (access modifiers, `static`, `final`)

Comment: Having String parameter instead of the Class object is hardcode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use

```
public final Logger = LogFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

For one this will ensure always the correct class name even after a refactoring of the class name. The overhead of one logger instance per instantiated object vs per class is neglectable.

I only use a static logger when I need to log something in as static context and then initialize it with your first approach.

Answer (score 9):

Use the first one

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SignUpController.class);
```

Because, that api (which is accepting class object), the method internally calls **fully qualified class name**, so the logging control/configuration can be done properly.

I prefer `private static final` because

**private**: for the logger instance should not be available to outside the class

**static**: there is no use of having separate instance for each object of a class

**final** to not to change the reference once it has been initialized.

Answer (score 3):

This solution:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SignUpController.class);
```

has the slight disadvantage that it gets copied and pasted into other classes and it is easy to forget to adjust the class name. Thus I prefer this solution which is safe for "copy & paste":

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
```